# How to show Admob interstitial on app start and exit

Tags: android, admob

I can make to show Admob Interstitial on App start, I also can make to show Admob Interstitial on App exit. But now, I want to show Admob Interstitial when App start AND exit. I have tried to combine 2 codes, one for the app start and one for the app exit, but result only show ads on app start, the ad does not appear on app exit.

Here my code:

```
    InterstitialAd interstitial;
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-2869508995487312/2690564381";
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.science_layout);

    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostResume();
    displayInterstitial();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    displayInterstitial();
}

// Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
    public void displayInterstitial() {
      if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        interstitialAd.show();
      }
    }
```

Anyone can help me fix code or provide new solutions? Thanks & Best regards !

Comment: Don't do it. It's an immediate uninstall for most users.

Comment: I just do it for sub_activity, not for main_activity or Home_activity :)

Comment: The easy way is to create an app exit button then call interstitial.show(); sending them back to your home activity. You can call onBackPressed() but that will create other problems and anger your user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's guidelines for interstitial ads clearly says that it is not recommended to show ads on app load or exit.

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6066980?hl=en

**> App load or exit (not recommended)**

> Avoid placing interstitial ads on app load, back buttons, and when
>   exiting apps as interstitials are meant to be placed in between
>   content.

Coming to your code, it should be working fine for app load time. Secondly , once an ad is loaded and displayed , you have to load it again to show it again. For calling it you should write "displayInterstitial();" in the onPause instead of onStop and only in one activity of the app.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

**However , I don't think you should show ads on app load and exit as it can cause issues with your admob account and will increase the uninstall rate of your app.**

Answer (score 0):

It's against Admob rules however i advice showing ad after splashscreen as google advices [Admob Interstitial after app loads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53208903/9374259)