# how to show admob interstitial on app start

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I need help 
how to show admob interstitial on app start
i want to trigger the admon interstitial when app launched 
for the record my app is a swipe tab content 
Pleas i need any solution 
any one have an idea

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("");

        //google ads Banner
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1417847946178022/7723890794");

        // Create ad request.
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);


        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        final ActionBar finalActionBar = actionBar;
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                finalActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });




        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });


    }

    // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that according to the [disallowed admob implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en):

> App load or exit
>
> Do not place interstitial ads on app load and when exiting apps as interstitials should only be placed in between pages of app content.

Failure to adhere to this policy might lead to the disabling of ad-serving to your app.

If you still want this, you can display in your `onResume's` method:

```
boolean isAdShown;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!isAdShown) {
        displayInterstitial();
        isAdShown = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No I don't want this  Give me an allowed method . please

Comment: So you mean I should use onPause() method . ok then just show me with codes

Answer (score 0):

You should not place interstitial ads on app load and when exiting apps as However. You can show Interstitial after app load, with such practice you have to implement a splash screen in your app and show interstitial after it.

> An interstitial ad launches while the user is idle on the ‘Home
>   Screen’ of the app. This implementation is in violation of our
>   policies . One potential way to fix this violation, would be to
>   implement a splash page that launches as the first screen of the app,
>   before the ‘Home Screen’. The Interstitial ad should then launch in
>   the transition between the splash screen and the ‘Home Screen’.

Reference : -- > [Google Blog](https://www.blog.google/products/admob/using-splash-pages-to-avoid-unexpected-launch-interstitials/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21358741)

Comment: Couldn't agree more, just updated the answer, Thanks